# Monitor job status in the loop in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to know if exists some pattern for following scenario:

1. I need call via REST API some long durable job which return me response containing job instance id a current status of job(STARTED, PROCESSING, SUCCESS FAILED, CANCELLED and so on)
2. After this I need to call another endpoint with job instance id from previous call to check if my job finnished or not.
3. The second step will be executed many time in the loop with some delay and of course with defined max count of checks.
4. Such routine will be always called from **current thread** and method will be blocked until some final status achieved or max check count or some exception during monitoring.

My idea is something like that developer will implemented some interface ExecutableMonitoredJob with two methods where first one will execute some operation and another one will determine if we are finnished or not. I would like to have it very abstract because operation might not be only REST call but for example also some db stored procedure or file creation. So second method to monitor status can have different implementation. Further, I would like to have possibility to access return value from first operation in the form of some context.

I looked at some tutorials in spring batch but I think that would be a little big overkill for now.

Does exist some suitable solution for my problem?

thanks